# potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'playtimer' used

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char str[256];
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    int h[3];
    SDL_TimerID playtimer, fpstimer;

    if (!init())
        return 1;

    if (argc>1) {
        if (!strcmp(argv[1],"-l") && (argc==3)) {
            mode = PLAY;
            if (!viewer->open(argv[2])) {
                error("Unable to load data file\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        } else if (!strcmp(argv[1], "-w") && (argc==3)) {
            mode = SIMULATE;
            fp = fopen(argv[2], "wb");
            fwrite(h, sizeof(int), 3, fp);
        } else {
            printf("Invalid command line argument. Usage: fluid [-l|-w <filename>]\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    } else {
        mode = SIMULATE;
    }

    if (mode == SIMULATE)
        simthread = SDL_CreateThread(simulate, NULL);

    if (mode == PLAY)
        playtimer = SDL_AddTimer(1000/16, timer_proc, NULL);

    fpstimer = SDL_AddTimer(1000, showfps, NULL);
    EventLoop(fp);
    SDL_RemoveTimer(fpstimer);
    if (mode==PLAY)
        SDL_RemoveTimer(playtimer);

    if (mode == SIMULATE) {
        quitting = true;
        SDL_WaitThread(simthread, NULL);
    }

    if (fp && (mode == SIMULATE)) {
        int pos;
        h[0] = h[1] = N+2;
        h[2] = simframes;
        pos = ftell(fp);
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
        fwrite(h, sizeof(int), 3, fp);
        fclose(fp);
        printf("%d frames written to file %s, %d kiB\n", simframes, argv[2], pos>>10);
    }
```

Could you help me with this problem, please? Thanks in advance.

The above is my code shown. The errors and warnings are below:

> warning C4101: 'str' : unreferenced local variable -
>
> warning C4715: 'SDL_main' : not all control paths return a value -
>
> error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable
>   'playtimer' used

Comment: Please learn to format the code. Its very important for anyone to look at the code. Also, I have not corrected syntax mistakes like missing the closing brace for main.

Comment: Sorry for that, as it is my first question.

Comment: Where is `mode` declared?

Answer (score 2):

The only place you initialize `playtimer` is in

```
if (mode == PLAY)
    playtimer = SDL_AddTimer(1000/16, timer_proc, NULL);
```

This ia a conditional initialization and means `playtimer` may or may not be initialized in the following code.  Then you have

```
if (mode==PLAY)
    SDL_RemoveTimer(playtimer);
```

So if you reach `SDL_RemoveTimer(playtimer);` `playtimer` may or may not have been initialized because of the first if statement.  Now we can reason that since both if conditions have the same condition then `playtimer` must be initialized and we are okay.  Unfortunately trying to get the compiler to see that is extremely hard and more than likely would be something that compiler vendors chose not to implement.  Also if this is a multi threaded program `mode` could change in between the two if statements and a compiler would not be able to analyze that.

I suggest that you combine both statements into a single if block to guarantee that `playtimer` is initialized when it is used:

```
if (mode == PLAY)
{
    playtimer = SDL_AddTimer(1000/16, timer_proc, NULL);
    SDL_RemoveTimer(playtimer);
}
```

I would also suggest you do the same thing for `simthread`.

Comment: Also, I don't see `mode` declared anywhere inside `main`. Which probably means that `mode` is declared outside, in namespace scope. Under these circumstances, from the compiler's point of view any intermediate call (like `EventLoop(fp)`) can potentially change `mode`. Most likely if `mode` were local the compiler would not have issued that warning. It is smart enough for that.